# Jenkins - how to create a temp file in workspace on slave node

Tags: jenkins

I am a newbie to Jenkins. I created a custom plugin, in which I am creating a temporary file in the job's workspace using `FilePath.createTempTextFile()`. It works fine on the master node, but on the slave node (Ubuntu Linux), it throws:

```
IOException: failed to create temp file in /home/jenkins/<job_name>/workspace
```

How do I create a file in the workspace on a slave node?

Comment: After some struggle I did understand that the files are not created  on the slave machine. While the code is executed on the slave, the files are created on the master machine and are remote transferred to the salve and executed. I could understand this from [link](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html).

Comment: And also ensure to use the **build.workspace()** for creating the temporary file. Because in my case, I also created a subfolder in the workspace and used that FilePath